# How do I append a specific cell to a specific row in the outer table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, html-table

I have a dynamic table I am trying to build.

The first 2 columns are hard coded (think headers) and I need to dynamically add columns based on looping through the contents of an XML file.

Each cell of the 2nd row contains a sub-table.

Looping through the XML file, how would I dynamically add "XXX" to the *outer* table in the 3rd row, "YYY" to the 4th row, and so on?

--I have re-posted more of the table.  Note that the contents of the 3rd and 4th cells of each row are dynamically generated from the XML (could be many more based on the XML).  I have hard-coded the contents for the purposes of getting help. There are more rows, but if I can get past this point, I should be good.--

```
<table class="someclass" border="1" id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Criteria</th>
        <th>Page</th>
            <th width="190px">
                Person 1 - <span id="name1" name="name1">Joe</span>
            </th>
            <th width="190px">
                Person 2 - <span id="name1" name="name1">Bob</span>
            </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Stats
        </td>
        <td class="page">
        </td>
        <td>
            <table id="stats1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">ST:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseST1" name="baseST1" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">HP:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseHPs1" name="baseHPs1" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">DX:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseDX1" name="baseDX1" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">Will:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseWill1" name="baseWill1" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">IQ:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseIQ1" name="baseIQ1" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">Per:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="basePer1" name="basePer1" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">HT:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseHT1" name="baseHT1" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">FP:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseFP1" name="baseFP1" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">Speed:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="BS1" name="BS1" type="text" class="statsCalc" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">Move:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="BM1" name="BM1" type="text" class="statsCalc" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">B Lift:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="BL1" name="BL1" type="text" class="statsCalc" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">Dodge:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="Dodge1" name="Dodge1" type="text" class="statsCalc" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table id="stats2">
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">ST:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseST2" name="baseST2" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">HP:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseHPs2" name="baseHPs2" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">DX:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseDX2" name="baseDX2" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">Will:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseWill2" name="baseWill2" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">IQ:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseIQ2" name="baseIQ2" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">Per:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="basePer2" name="basePer2" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">HT:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseHT2" name="baseHT2" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">FP:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="baseFP2" name="baseFP2" type="text" class="stats" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">Speed:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="BS2" name="BS2" type="text" class="statsCalc" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">Move:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="BM2" name="BM2" type="text" class="statsCalc" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="StatTitle">B Lift:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="BL2" name="BL2" type="text" class="statsCalc" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                    <td class="StatTitle">Dodge:</td>
                    <td class="StatValue"><input id="Dodge2" name="Dodge2" type="text" class="statsCalc" disabled="disabled"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Maneuver
        </td>
        <td class="page">
            363
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="maneuver1">
                <input type="hidden" name="person1" />
            </div>
            <div id="throwDiv1" name="throwDiv1" class="throw">
                <label class="throw">Lbs</label>
                <input type="text" id="throwInput1" name="throwInput1" class="throw" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="maneuver2">
                <input type="hidden" name="person2" />
            </div>
            <div id="throwDiv2" name="throwDiv2" class="throw">
                <label class="throw">Lbs</label>
                <input type="text" id="throwInput2" name="throwInput2" class="throw" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Weapon
        </td>
        <td class="page">
            99
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="weapon1" id="weapon1">
            </select>
            <a href="#" class="weaponFlyouts">
                Details
                <span class="weaponMaster">
                    <img class="callout" src="images/callout.gif" />
                    <span id="weaponName1" name="weaponName1" class="weaponName"></span><img id="weaponImage1" src="">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Caliber</th>
                            <th>Damage</th>
                            <th>Acc</th>
                            <th>Range</th>
                            <th>Weight</th>
                            <th>ROF</th>
                            <th>Cap</th>
                            <th>ST</th>
                            <th>Bulk</th>
                            <th>Recoil</th>
                            <th>Source</th>
                            <th>Page</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap><span id="weaponCal1" name="weaponCal1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponDamage1" name="weaponDamage1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponAcc1" name="weaponAcc1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponRange1" name="weaponRange1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponWeight1" name="weaponWeight1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponROF1" name="weaponROF1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponCap1" name="weaponCap1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponST1" name="weaponST1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponBulk1" name="weaponBulk1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponRecoil1" name="weaponRecoil1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponSource1" name="weaponSource1"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponPage1" name="weaponPage1"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="weapon2" id="weapon2">
            </select>
            <a href="#" class="weaponFlyouts">
                Details
                <span class="weaponMaster">
                    <img class="callout" src="images/callout.gif" />
                    <span id="weaponName2" name="weaponName2" class="weaponName"></span><img id="weaponImage2" src="">
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Caliber</th>
                            <th>Damage</th>
                            <th>Acc</th>
                            <th>Range</th>
                            <th>Weight</th>
                            <th>ROF</th>
                            <th>Cap</th>
                            <th>ST</th>
                            <th>Bulk</th>
                            <th>Recoil</th>
                            <th>Source</th>
                            <th>Page</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap><span id="weaponCal2" name="weaponCal2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponDamage2" name="weaponDamage2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponAcc2" name="weaponAcc2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponRange2" name="weaponRange2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponWeight2" name="weaponWeight2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponROF2" name="weaponROF2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponCap2" name="weaponCap2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponST2" name="weaponST2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponBulk2" name="weaponBulk2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponRecoil2" name="weaponRecoil2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponSource2" name="weaponSource2"></span></td>
                            <td><span id="weaponPage2" name="weaponPage2"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There are more rows, but this more or less shows the structure.

I have jQuery working on the 1st and 2nd row (the 2nd having the sub-table), but my code keeps getting confused between the outer and inner tables.

Comment: `but my code keeps getting confused` -- Code doesn't get confused. It does what it is set to do by the developer, who may be confused. Can you add the basic structure of your inner and outer tables please as they are actually showing in the mark-up. Giving you a solution which requires traversal to an outer table is not going to be accurate if the exact mark-up is not there.

Comment: As it currently stands without the actual mark-up this question is to localized.

Answer (score 0):

I would split your table into thead and tbody as follows:

```
<table class="someclass" border="1" id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Criteria</th>
        <th>Page</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Stats
        </td>
        <td class="page">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Row 3
        </td>
        <td class="page">
            363
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Row 4
        </td>
        <td class="page">
            400
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It seems from your description that you have your headers, that second row, and the rows after that. In jQuery you could then do the following:

```
//start off with your second row
var body = "<tr><td>Stats</td><td class="page"></td>";
//loop through the rest of your rows and for each row do:
body += "<tr><td>Row 3</td><td class="page">363</td>"; //etc...
//then set your tbody to have that text
$("#myTable > tbody").html(body);
```